# where can I find the abbreviation for MSO, OP, SO?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

Are there any more abbreviations like MSO, OP, SO ?

I just came to know OP= original post.

can any one tell me the rest?

Comment: "LMGTFY" = Please search before asking.  ;)

Comment: @Bill haha... yes, riiight... Kinda like WTF=My, that is unexpected!

Comment: @BilltheLizard I searched with po and find the answer, then I find there ppl are using MSO, SO. how do I know the link of Dictionary or Commonly -used terms..... any way thanks for your answer and your vote.

Comment: @PadmaKumar I did a [Meta search for 'abbreviations'](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=abbreviations) and the glossary post came up in the results.  I admit, it does help when you've seen the post before and you already know what you're looking for.

Comment: @BilltheLizard i just searched with keys not the dictionary term. I am sorry for that.

Comment: @PadmaKumar No worries.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
MSO - Meta StackOverflow
SO - StackOverflow
OP - Original Poster
```

Don't know what others you may mean.

```
SU - SuperUser
SF - ServerFault
CW - Community Wiki
SE - Stack Exchange
SEI - Stack Exchange, Inc
SOFU - StackOverflow + ServerFault + SuperUser
```

All of these appear in the [Stack Overflow Glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms).